# Why VM.native_memory detail BOOTSTRAP has been growing in jdk1.8?

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, jvm

My `Spring-boot 2.7.9` web server, everyday my server killed by `k8s`.

I add JVM start jvm param `-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail` to  check this problem,
find `type=Internal` in BOOTSTRAP memory more and more

who tell me reason? thanks.

[image]

some code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v98PG.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Do you have variable members in your Spring component, services, etc. like `Map`, `List`... that, day after day, would be filled?

Comment: Not see any Map, List that, day after day, would be filled, thanks.

Comment: my code contains JNI call, when JNI called native_memory detail occurred [BOOTSTRAP], other none.

Comment: Add samples of your code, maybe, to see if we can track something explaining your problem, inside? If you leave us with your screenshot only, it's difficult for us to help you.